# How do I ignore files in Subversion?

Tags: svn, command

How do I ignore files in Subversion?

Also, how do I find files which are not under version control?

Answer (score 804, accepted):

(This answer has been updated to match SVN 1.8 and 1.9's behaviour)

You have 2 questions:

## Marking files as ignored:

By "ignored file" I mean the file won't appear in lists even as "unversioned": your SVN client will pretend the file doesn't exist at all in the filesystem.

Ignored files are specified by a "file pattern". The syntax and format of file patterns is explained in SVN's online documentation: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html "File Patterns in Subversion".

Subversion, as of version 1.8 (June 2013) and later, supports 3 different ways of specifying file patterns. Here's a summary with examples:

### 1 - Runtime Configuration Area - `global-ignores` option:

- This is a **client-side only** setting, so your `global-ignores` list won't be shared by other users, and it applies to all repos you checkout onto your computer.
- This setting is defined in your Runtime Configuration Area file:

  - Windows (file-based) - `C:\Users\{you}\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config`
  - Windows (registry-based) - `Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config\Miscellany\global-ignores` in both `HKLM` and `HKCU`.
  - Linux/Unix - `~/.subversion/config`

### 2 - The `svn:ignore` property, which is set on directories (not files):

- This is stored within the repo, so other users will have the same ignore files. Similar to how `.gitignore` works.
- `svn:ignore` is applied to directories and is non-recursive or inherited. Any file or *immediate* subdirectory of the parent directory that matches the File Pattern will be excluded.
- While SVN 1.8 adds the concept of "inherited properties", the `svn:ignore` property itself is ignored in non-immediate descendant directories:

  ```
    cd ~/myRepoRoot                             # Open an existing repo.
    echo "foo" > "ignoreThis.txt"                # Create a file called "ignoreThis.txt".

    svn status                                  # Check to see if the file is ignored or not.
    > ?    ./ignoreThis.txt
    > 1 unversioned file                        # ...it is NOT currently ignored.

    svn propset svn:ignore "ignoreThis.txt" .   # Apply the svn:ignore property to the "myRepoRoot" directory.
    svn status
    > 0 unversioned files                       # ...but now the file is ignored!

    cd subdirectory                             # now open a subdirectory.
    echo "foo" > "ignoreThis.txt"                # create another file named "ignoreThis.txt".

    svn status
    > ?    ./subdirectory/ignoreThis.txt        # ...and is is NOT ignored!
    > 1 unversioned file
  ```

  (So the file `./subdirectory/ignoreThis` is not ignored, even though "`ignoreThis.txt`" is applied on the `.` repo root).
- Therefore, to apply an ignore list recursively you must use `svn propset svn:ignore <filePattern> . --recursive`.

  - This will create a copy of the property on every subdirectory.
  - If the `<filePattern>` value is different in a child directory then the child's value completely overrides the parents, so there is no "additive" effect.
  - So if you change the `<filePattern>` on the root `.`, then you must change it with `--recursive` to overwrite it on the child and descendant directories.
- I note that the command-line syntax is counter-intuitive.

  - I started-off assuming that you would ignore a file in SVN by typing something like `svn ignore pathToFileToIgnore.txt` however this is not how SVN's ignore feature works.

### 3- The `svn:global-ignores` property. Requires SVN 1.8 (June 2013):

- This is similar to `svn:ignore`, except it makes use of SVN 1.8's "inherited properties" feature.
- Compare to `svn:ignore`, the file pattern is automatically applied in every descendant directory (not just immediate children).

  - This means that is unnecessary to set `svn:global-ignores` with the `--recursive` flag, as inherited ignore file patterns are automatically applied as they're inherited.
- Running the same set of commands as in the previous example, but using `svn:global-ignores` instead:

  ```
    cd ~/myRepoRoot                                    # Open an existing repo
    echo "foo" > "ignoreThis.txt"                       # Create a file called "ignoreThis.txt"
    svn status                                         # Check to see if the file is ignored or not
    > ?    ./ignoreThis.txt
    > 1 unversioned file                               # ...it is NOT currently ignored

    svn propset svn:global-ignores "ignoreThis.txt" .
    svn status
    > 0 unversioned files                              # ...but now the file is ignored!

    cd subdirectory                                    # now open a subdirectory
    echo "foo" > "ignoreThis.txt"                       # create another file named "ignoreThis.txt"
    svn status
    > 0 unversioned files                              # the file is ignored here too!
  ```

### For TortoiseSVN users:

This whole arrangement was confusing for me, because TortoiseSVN's terminology (as used in their Windows Explorer menu system) was initially misleading to me - I was unsure what the significance of the Ignore menu's "Add  recursively", "Add *" and "Add " options. I hope this post explains how the Ignore feature ties-in to the SVN Properties feature. That said, I suggest using the command-line to set ignored files so you get a feel for how it works instead of using the GUI, and only using the GUI to manipulate properties after you're comfortable with the command-line.

## Listing files that are ignored:

The command `svn status` will hide ignored files (that is, files that match an RCA `global-ignores` pattern, or match an immediate parent directory's `svn:ignore` pattern or match any ancesor directory's `svn:global-ignores` pattern.

Use the `--no-ignore` option to see those files listed. Ignored files have a status of `I`, then pipe the output to `grep` to only show lines starting with "I".

The command is:

```
svn status --no-ignore | grep "^I"
```

For example:

```
svn status
> ? foo                             # An unversioned file
> M modifiedFile.txt                # A versioned file that has been modified

svn status --no-ignore
> ? foo                             # An unversioned file
> I ignoreThis.txt                  # A file matching an svn:ignore pattern
> M modifiedFile.txt                # A versioned file that has been modified

svn status --no-ignore | grep "^I"
> I ignoreThis.txt                  # A file matching an svn:ignore pattern
```

ta-da!

Comment: To find ignored files: svn status -u -v --no-ignore |grep "^I"|awk "{print \$2}"

Comment: if you want to ignore file ./FolderA/FolderB/FileToIgnore, do this from your . folder: svn propset svn:ignore "FileToIgnore" FolderA/FolderB/

Comment: Thanks.  Note that if you use single quotes in your awk programs, you don't need to escape the (commonly used there) dollar sign.  Just a nit. :-D

Comment: if you are ssh'ing `svn propedit svn:ignore .` and no text editor is configured you'll get an error message saying _svn: E205007: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found_ instead of getting an editor opened. So just specify _--editor-cmd nano_ like this `svn propedit svn:ignore . --editor-cmd nano`

Comment: This command should be executed inside the containing-files-to-ignore folder? I mean... oh... `.` is a folder to propset on?

Comment: @Nakilon yes. You can specify the folder, and . is the current folder

Comment: You can also ignore files with a specific filename in all subfolders using the "--recursive" argument. i.e. **svn propset svn:ignore "*.jpg" . --recursive**

Comment: A simpler alternative to awk is grep : `svn status | grep '^?'`

Comment: Note that in Windows, the first command may fail depending on what files are in the current directory with `(filename) is not under version control`. In this case you must use the second command instead to edit your ignore list. You may need to set your editor first with e.g. `set SVN_EDITOR=notepad`

Comment: `EDITOR=vi svn propedit svn:ignore .` solves any doubt

Comment: @Johnride you mean `-v`, don't you?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that svn propset overrides any previous svn propset.

Comment: I've add `bin` `debug` `obj` to `svn:global-ignores` but after that, when i `svn propget svn:global-ignores` it only return `obj` (the last one), 
how can I ignore multiple files/folders?

Comment: I sometimes prefer the `global-ignores` method over `svn propset svn:ignore` because the later will mark the directory as modified (wich  invites you to push the property to everyone, which is not always what you want).

Comment: Is "3" stored in the repo and shared with others? The answer states it is similar to "2" but the "global" part of "global-ignores" leads to me assuming that it is locally set only.

Comment: Is the property "svn:ignore" stored? Where? Is it committed? How I can view its value when browsing the repository?

Answer (score 96):

Use the following command to create a list not under version control files.

```
svn status | grep "^\?" | awk "{print \$2}" > ignoring.txt
```

Then edit the file to **leave just the files you want actually to ignore**. Then use this one to ignore the files listed in the file:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F ignoring.txt .
```

Note the dot at the end of the line. It tells SVN that the property is being set on the current directory.

Delete the file:

```
rm ignoring.txt
```

Finally commit,

```
svn ci --message "ignoring some files"
```

You can then check which files are ignored via:

```
svn proplist -v
```

Comment: Nice. A minor improvement is `svn status | awk "/^?/ {print \$2}" > ignoring.txt`.

Comment: why delete the file? keep it in repo if u need to re create/add/remove

Comment: Note this solution will not ignore files in subdirectories (even if they show up in ignoring.txt).

Comment: Would that keep existing ignores? If not, how to do it in one command (i.e. --no-ignores and keep also lines preceded by I )?

Comment: This would overwrite your current ignores, try: `svn pg svn:ignore . >> ignore.txt` after the first command to append the current ignores to the file.

Comment: @tgkprog it's just a one time use to load the files into the properties. So the file is not guaranteed to contain the same as what's in the properties. So it makes sense to delete it and get people to run `svn proplist -v` to check which files actually are ignored.

Comment: Seems like not working for `node_modules` folder, I still have to manually set it to ignore in svn gui.

Answer (score 79):

## .gitignore like approach

You can ignore a file or directory like .gitignore. Just create a text file of list of directories/files you want to ignore and run the code below:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F ignorelist.txt .
```

OR if you don't want to use a text file, you can do it like this:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "first
 second
 third" .
```

[Source: Karsten's Blog - Set svn:ignore for multiple files from command line](http://kthoms.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/set-svnignore-for-multiple-files-from-command-line/)

Comment: Note that if you later modify your ignore file, you do need to rerun the `svn:ignore` command (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58380306/189518)

Answer (score 51):

If you are using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/), right-click on a file and then select **TortoiseSVN / Add to ignore list**. This will add the file/wildcard to the `svn:ignore` property.

`svn:ignore` will be checked when you are checking in files, and matching files will be ignored. I have the following ignore list for a Visual Studio .NET project:

```
bin obj
*.exe
*.dll
_ReSharper
*.pdb
*.suo
```

You can find this list in the context menu at **TortoiseSVN / Properties**.

Answer (score 45):

As nobody seems to have mentioned it...

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

Then edit the contents of the file to specify the patterns to ignore, exit the editor and you're all done.

Comment: This answer was useful. In my case I needed to change "." to the sub-directory of the file I wanted to ignore and just specify the file pattern. Also, the first time, I needed run this (I'm on Mac): export SVN_EDITOR="nano"

Answer (score 22):

I found the article  *[.svnignore Example for Java](http://sethholloway.com/svnignore-example-for-java/)*.

Example: .svnignore for Ruby on Rails,

```
/log

/public/*.JPEG
/public/*.jpeg
/public/*.png
/public/*.gif

*.*~
```

And after that:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .
```

Examples for .gitignore. You can use for your .svnignore

https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: i did as u said... but when i run svn status. it still shows the ignored files with "?"

Comment: I never checked with svn status, but with svn add * and after that svn commit, ignoring files is doesn't commit.

Comment: if a file "a.txt" already in version control, then the ignore is done by the command like "svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore a.txt" ? is it correct ?

Comment: If you add "a.txt" in your .svnignore file, I am not sure, but command should be properly.

Answer (score 10):

When using propedit make sure not have any trailing spaces as that will cause the file to be excluded from the ignore list.

These are inserted automatically if you've use tab-autocomplete on linux to create the file to begin with:

```
svn propset svn:ignore 'file1
file2' .
```

Comment: This only works for some shells, such as bash.

Note that reissuing the propset command overwrites the previous set of patterns.

Comment: So **file1** and **file2** have to be on separate lines?

Answer (score 8):

Also, if you use Tortoise SVN you can do this:

1. In context menu select "TortoiseSVN", then "Properties"
2. In appeared window click "New", then "Advanced"
3. In appeared window opposite to "Property name" select or type "svn:ignore", opposite to "Property value" type desired file name or folder name or file mask (in my case it was "*/target"), click "Apply property recursively"
4. Ok. Ok.
5. Commit

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is:

```
svn st | awk '/^?/{print $2}' > svnignore.txt && svn propget svn:ignore >> svnignore.txt && svn propset svn:ignore -F svnignore.txt . && rm svnignore.txt
```

or line by line

```
svn st | awk '/^?/{print $2}' > svnignore.txt 
svn propget svn:ignore >> svnignore.txt 
svn propset svn:ignore -F svnignore.txt . 
rm svnignore.txt
```

What it does:

1. Gets the status files from the svn
2. Saves all files with **?** to the file "svnignore.txt"
3. Gets the already ignored files and appends them to the file "svnignore.txt"
4. Tells the svn to ignore the files in "svnignore.txt"
5. Removes the file

Answer (score 6):

A more readable version of [bkbilly's answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30528955/7724)

```
svn st | awk '/^?/{print $2}' > svnignore.txt
svn propget svn:ignore >> svnignore.txt
svn propset svn:ignore -F svnignore.txt .
rm svnignore.txt
```

What it does:

1. Gets the status files from the svn
2. Saves all files with **?** to the file "svnignore.txt"
3. Gets the already ignored files and appends them to the file "svnignore.txt"
4. Tells the svn to ignore the files in "svnignore.txt"
5. Removes the file

Comment: I like bkbilly's answer, but this version breaks each line to make it more readable, and removes the && which in my tests did nothing, since the first line always creates the temporary file, and this same temporary file always gets into the ignore list.

Comment: An edit proposition would have more appropriate in this case. Appreciate the effort !

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation yet to suggest an edit. but I don't want to ruin a good protocol.  Is there an simple README on guidelines for when to it is better to suggest and edit rather than post a new answer etc?

Comment: If your answer is exactly the same as the one posted a year and a half ago, it's pretty straight forward. You even copied the "*What it does*" explanation.

Answer (score 6):

1. cd ~/.subversion
2. open config
3. find the line like 'global-ignores'
4. set ignore file type like this: global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.pyc *.pyo
   88  *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store node_modules output

Comment: Thank you, your answer is the only one that mentions the `config` file.

Comment: This answer mentions it as well @HenriquedeSousa https://stackoverflow.com/a/86052/7724 and also explains that it is a local client-only way of ignoring files.

Answer (score 4):

`svn status` will tell you which files are not in SVN, as well as what's changed.

Look at the [SVN properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html) for the ignore property.

For all things SVN, the [Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/index.html) is required reading.

Answer (score 4):

You can also set a global ignore pattern in SVN's configuration file.

Comment: Can you set an ignore pattern for a specific repository?

Answer (score 4):

What **worked** for me (*I am using TortoiseSVN v1.13.1*):

## How do I ignore files in Subversion?

1.In File Explorer, right-click on SVN *project folder-name*
2.Click on "SVN Commit..."
3.A "commit" window will appear
4.**Right-click** on the folder/file that you want to ignore
5.Click on "Add to ignore list"
6.Select the folder/file name you want to ignore

- There's a few choices(4 for me), if you choose only the folder/file name, it will be added to svn:ignore list
- if you choose the folder/file name, with (recursively), it will be added to svn:global-ignores. This is what i normally choose, as this change is inherited automatically by all sub-directories.
  [image]

7.**Commit** the "property change" to SVN

## Also, how do I find files which are not under version control?

After Step 3 above, click on "Show unversioned files" as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the command **svn status** on your working copy to show the status of files, files that are not yet under version control (and not ignored) will have a question mark next to them.

As for ignoring files you need to edit the svn:ignore property, read the chapter Ignoring Unversioned Items in the svnbook at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html. The book also describes more about using svn status.

Answer (score 2):

[Adding a directory to subversion, and ignoring the directory contents](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/adding-directory-subversion-and-ignoring-directory-contents)

```
svn propset svn:ignore '\*.*' .
```

or

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*' .
```

Answer (score 2):

SVN `ignore` is easy to manage in TortoiseSVN. Open TortoiseSVN and right-click on file menu then select Add to ignore list.

This will add the files in the `svn:ignore` property.
When we checking in the files then those file which is matched with `svn:ignore` that will be ignored and will not commit.

In Visual Studio project we have added following files to ignore:

```
bin obj
*.exe
*.dll
*.pdb
*.suo
```

We are managing source code on SVN of [Comparetrap](http://www.comparetrap.com/) using this method successfully

Answer (score 0):

1. open you use JetBrains Product(i.e. Pycharm)
2. then click the 'commit' button on the top toolbar or use shortcut 'ctrl + k'
   [screenshot_toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwwNN.png)
3. on the commit interface, move your unwanted files to another change list as follows.
   [screenshot_commit_change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWqNP.png)
4. next time you can only commit default change list.