# Failing to ignore svn-controlled directory when doing svn update

Tags: linux, svn

Based on [How do I ignore a directory with SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn) I tried

```
svn propset svn:ignore /foo/bar/ .
```

But when doing 
    svn update /foo

I get this error:

```
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/foo/bar/'
svn: PROPFIND of '/foo/bar': 405 Method Not Allowed (http://svn.assembla.com)
```

The reason why I am trying to skip /foo/bar is because I replaced it with a symlink to /some/other/dir

```
ln -s /some/other/dir /foo/bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the slash on the end. It may be getting confused, as symlinks are generally referred to without a slash on them.

After talking with poster out-of-band, it turns out he wanted to have the same `/foo/bar` tracked in svn, but only ignored for this particular checkout. SVN was having none of it, as there were things in the way that weren't the right type.

The solution is to move the tracked directory to another path and symlink checkout-side appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The svn:ignore property is only used during svn status and svn add commands, no other operation pays attention to it, such as update.

Also, do you have your checkout rooted at /, since the property you have /foo/bar.