# How can I remove a file from my svn working copy without deleting it?

Tags: svn

I accidentally added a file to my svn working copy that I don't want to check in (a test image).  I haven't commited yet, so how do I remove the file from my svn working copy without deleting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[svn revert](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re25.html) filename

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed!  This is why I LOVE StackO!

Answer (score 3):

If it's in `A` state, then simple `svn revert` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In case it happens to a folder you can use the same command adding the desired  level to apply recursivity

```
svn revert --depth infinity [folder_name]
```

It may be useful to add the folder to the ignore list in case you are interested in maintaining it under the same folder structure without worrying about an accidental add/commit. A helpful post about this aspect
can be found here [How do I ignore a directory with SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-with-svn)