# Versions svn:ignore

Tags: svn, versions

I'm using [versions svn](http://versionsapp.com)

How can I add `svn:ignore` to a folder?
I have a folder called `cache` that I'd like to ignore.
Adding `*` from the ignore panel doesn't seem to do the trick.

Has anyone successfully do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do an ignore with Versions mac software. It needs to be done before you commit. After you commit, it won't work.

Thanks,
Tee