# How to set SVN multiple properties in one go

Tags: svn

I have several (around 20) svn propedit ignore statements to perform manually.

Is there anyway I can do this all in one go, instead of one by one?. IIRC, all the ignore properties are stored in one file. So I could simply edit that file and update it with my multiple lines IIRC?

BTW I am using the command line tools on Ubuntu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn

Comment: All ignores for the same directory or different directories? It's one ignore property per directory but with multiple values per property.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows, open up a command prompt (cmd.exe). Powershell won't work.

Run: `set SVN_EDITOR="%windir%\system32\notepad.exe"`

Then: `svn propedit svn:ignore [directory]` or `svn propedit svn:ignore .` with a space and dot at the end.

Then in Notepad, write a folder or file on each line, then save the text file to its current location. Doing this will automatically communicate back to SVN that these are the things that you want to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

bash oneliner

```
svn propset svn:ignore ".project"$'\n'".settings"$'\n'".buildpath" yourpath
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `svn propedit svn:ignore [directory]`. It opens the editor in your `SVN_EDITOR` enviroment variable or falls back to `EDITOR` (IIRC). You might need to set it if it's not automatically set in your ~/.profile. The editor opens and you can then add several ignore patterns, each on a different line.