# SVN ignore a versioned files during update thru svn commandline

Tags: svn

I am using svn commandline and i want to ignore few files from getting updated in my working copy. I tried `svn proset svn:ignore -F file.txt .`, it says "`property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'`", still when i update it updates all the files. however it works fine with tortoisesvn, but i need it for a linux machine hence looking for an commandline option to achieve it.

Comment: So, you have versioned files which you want `svn update` to ignore, without unversioning them first? I think you will have to write a script that pipes the paths of the files you **do** want to update, excluding the paths you **don't** want to update, to the `svn up` command

Comment: Thanks Sameer Singh, I have done it like that now.

Comment: @anand Can you please share those scripts ? It will be very helpful for others. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there aren't any direct way thru SVN, created a script to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how it appears to work with tortoise, but svn:ignore does not affect the svn update command.  You can look here for some other options: [Ignore a folder during SVN updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984625/ignore-a-folder-during-svn-updates)

Comment: Thanks ioscode, there is an option with tortoise svn "unversion and add to ignore list", this helps to ignore the files. Yep i saw the other link, where in it is for folder, whereas im looking for files.

Comment: @anand do you really want those files **deleted** from the repository & ignored in the future?

Comment: @alroc, I don't want to delete the file, I just not want to update the file during update. I have asked the developer to deal in different way, but he insist this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ignore a file that is versioned.

If you want to ignore specific items when updating, you need to explicitly tell svn which items you *do* want updated.

For example, if you have files A through E, but want to ignore the consonants when updating, you have to do this:

`svn update A E`

Comment: Thanks alroc, but there are lot of files under that folder, hence it will be difficult to update one by one