# How to make svn update excluding folders with certain name

Tags: svn, command-line

I need to update some svn storages. There are a lot of folders I don't need to updated in these storages. All of this folders are named identically, say, `FolderToSkip`. These folders are heavy weighted and not important for my purposes for now. So, I'd like to update svn storages skiping these `FolderToSkip` folders.

I can't use [svn:ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn), because it is only for files that are not already in the Subversion repository. These folders already is.

I can't use [svn update --set-depth exclude FolderToSkip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984625/ignore-a-folder-during-svn-updates), because it is just for the one specified path and I need all of folders with name `FolderToSkip`

Is it possible to get, what I want and how it can be done?

***EDIT:*** Folders to skip are placed in different paths of storages. For example,

```
~/loom/svnstore/foo/FolderToSkip
~/loom/svnstore/bar/trunk/2.1.0/var/FolderToSkip
~/loom/svnstore/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/FolderToSkip
...
```

And command for updating all files look like:

```
~/loom/svnstore$ svn up
```

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use single command, it will be set of `svn up` (at least 2)
2. Root of you tree **must** be updated separately, because it **require** defining `--depth 'files'` or `--set-depth  'files'`, while all updatable folders may use default 'infinity'
3. If you can prepare space-separated list of updatable folders, you can use (after `svn up --depth 'files'` in the root) `svn up PATH1 PATH2 ... PATHN`, and get as result only enumerated folder updated
4. If you can't prepare list, but can use good OS with grep and xargs and pipes, svn up with long path-list can be replaced with something like

`svn ls | grep -v FolderToSkip | xargs svn up`

Comment: Thank you. However it doesn't work. Maybe I gave wrong explanation. I updated the question.