# How to ignore folder without removing it from my repository

Tags: svn, repository

I have this tmp/ and cache/ directories, that keep generating files that don't need to be commited.

How can I set it so svn ignores them, but doesn't delete them or remove them from the repository, they are needed for the site to work.

Comment: So have you already added them (the files in the cache dir) to repository?

Comment: so you need to copy them somewhere, then perform `svn rm` to all of them, then add `svn:ignore` property, then put them back. It is the simplest (and the only) way to do what you want

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$ cd /path/to/app/tmp
$ svn propset svn:ignore '*' .
$ cd /path/to/app/cache
$ svn propset svn:ignore '*' .
```

EDIT: Here's the steps if you already previously committed

```
$ cd /path/to/app/tmp
$ svn st
M slkdjfag.jpg
M gasgsag.png
. #bunch of M's

$ svn rm * --force
$ svn ci -m'trunk: cleaning up tmp directory'
$ svn propset svn:ignore '*' .
$ touch a
$ svn st // shouldn't output anything
```

Comment: that's what i did, but I still get all the files M when I svn status

Comment: You need to remove those if you previously committed, `cd /path/to/app/tmp/ ; svn rm *`

Comment: If you have .svn dirs in them you must remove them too.

Comment: So basically, I can't remove a folder from SVN syncing and still keep it in repository, the best I can do is remove all the modifiable content, and set ignore to the content of the folder?

Comment: @Lachezar Todorov: you're absolutely wrong. There is no any valid reason ever to manually remove `.svn`

Comment: @mgPePe: unfortunately - yes, you cannot do that. svn doesn't have some sort of `forget` command

Comment: @zerkms - but I guess the solutions seems to be to just remove all the content of tmp throught `svn del tmp/*`

Comment: @mgPePe: not a good point at all. as soon as you'll perform any command on the top of `cache or tmp` dir - svn will notify you that there is some missed directory.

Comment: @mgPePe: I've explained in the comment to your question what you need to do. Now you're free either to follow best practice or try to fool svn (and have some headaches after)

Comment: @zerkms: isn't this what i said too? remove the content but keep the actual folder? Or am i missing something? is `svn rm` same as `svn del` ? (the crap content itself will get regenerated, which is okay after I ignore it as per instructions)

Comment: @mgPePe:  Lachezar Todorov told you `If you have .svn dirs in them you must remove them too` --- it is wrong. You **never** should do anything with `.svn` manually. I don't see any reason to call that advice a `good point`.

Comment: @zerkms let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1974/discussion-between-mgpepe-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 4):

The command is:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore ./some_path
```

You can use * for "any chars" in the path like, *.project if you want.

Tortoise svn is a good solution for user friendly interface(like Petar Ivanov says). If you are on PC it's "must have" software. If you are on other OS or want full control of svn I suggest you read more about command line working with svn. It's not hard and google knows many things about it :)

you can read more about it: [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/662.cfm)

And more about cmd svn: [here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/255/svn-command-line-tutorial-for-beginners-1/)

Comment: Hi, I did this and all files still appear when I type svn status. It seems svn ignore excludes the files altogether, doesn't stop syncing. But I don't want those folders deleted, since they are needed for project

Comment: @Todorov Using TortoiseSVN will delete the folder to be able to ignore it. `Delete and add to ignore list` is the only option. There's NO `Ignore` command :)

Comment: Delete in Tortoise means delete from svn not your current folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a svn property to the parent folder: svn:ignore.

If you use tortoise: `Right click -> Properties -> SVN -> Properties... -> (add or edit)`

In the console: `svn propset svn:ignore [path/file(s)]`

Comment: Hi, I did this and all files still appear when I type svn status. It seems svn ignore excludes the files altogether, doesn't stop syncing. But I don't want those folders deleted, since they are needed for project

Comment: those files **should not** be checked in - when you update they are not affected - that's what svn:ignore is ...

Comment: @Petar Ivanov: the files that have already added will be updated/committed on change as well. `svn:ignore` affects **only** to new files

Comment: that's what I am saying - those files should not be checked in