# SVN ignore problem in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, svn, osx-lion

Before installing Lion, when I tried to ignore something on my svn, I just typed the following command:

```
 svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

This opened a temporary file for the current directory with the selected editor and I could write there my patterns, which where ignored by svn.

After I installed Lion, when I type this command the following error appears: `The document “svn-prop.tmp” could not be opened. The file doesn’t exist.`

Did anybody else met this error before? (I tried googling, but I didn't find any solution).

---

SVN_EDITOR=/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit

Comment: The `svn-prop.tmp` file is created in the current directory. Did you check if you have write permissions? How is your EDITOR environment variable set?

Comment: I must have write permission, because the directory is my project's directory, but I am going to check it again.

Comment: Checked... I have write permission, I also added 777 access to the dir but neither before nor after not worked.

Comment: Anything strange defined in EDITOR? Which editor to you use?

Comment: I am using TextEdit. I've used this before too.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that with Lion it is no more possible to open a file with TextEdit on the command line giving the file name as argument.

A workaround is to use `open`

```
export SVN_EDITOR='open -e -W -n '
```

- `-e` tells to open with TextEdit (use `-a` if you want to specify a different application)
- `-W` tells open to wait for TextEdit to quit. If not specified svn propedit will read the file before it's edited and return telling the no changes were done.
- `-n` tells to open a new instance of TextEdit even if there is another one already open. On one hand it will avoid that you have to quit an open editor and on the other hand it was not working without the option :-)

Comment: Thanks! I am going home and try out this.