# Import home directory to svn without adding all its contents

Tags: svn, unix, version-control

I'm trying to add a couple of files in my home directory to my svn repository, namely `.vimrc` and `.bashrc`. How do I go about doing this? I don't want to import everything in my home directory because that would be too many files, I only want to add a couple of files from my home directory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to put these files into a separate directory (*e.g.* `${HOME}/dotfiles`) and symlink these into your `${HOME}` (*e.g.* `ln -s ${HOME}/dotfiles/vimrc ${HOME}/.vimrc`).

Then you can put your dotfiles directory under version control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add only the files you want and ignore the rest.

```
svn add filename
```

And ignore the rest as seen here [How do I ignore a directory with SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn) (also work for files)