# How can I exclude certain files within a tree from being subversioned?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have subversioned my entire folder which contains all the source files, binaries and other files my IDE (Visual Studio) uses. Now each time I do a build next time I do a svn commit, svn will upload my changed builds. How can I exclude certain files folders within a tree? (I only want my source files not my builds and IDE files subversioned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore file patterns selectively with the [svn:ignore property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn) for details on ignoring a directory.

Comment: Also here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html

Comment: ahh but that only ignores: "one-time process of adding unversioned files and directories to version control", how can I ignore items already added?

Comment: Ignoring items that are already added is the wrong way to do it. This would be very bad practice. With subversion, the easiest thing to do is start over. If you really want to maintain the history, you can probably remove them from the history with significant effort. I'd suggest checking out git as a much more flexible version control system. Dealing with 'mistakes' like this is more feasible.

Comment: The one other reasonable thing to do is to delete all of your build files from your work tree and commit this change. Now, they will no longer be pulled in so long as you use that commit or newer, and svn:ignore will take effect.