# Excluding specific files from commit/update in Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have created an SVN repository before. Now what I want to do is to prevent some specific files from update, since it is not needed for me to update them. I saw solutions for during the process of creating repo, but I did it long way back and I want to exclude some files now.

The situation is like the following:

```
repo/
updateme.txt
donotupdateme.txt
```

Here, I want donotupdateme.txt to stay the same while updateme.txt changes with the update operation.

p.s. I prefer doing this with Tortoise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a /etc/svn/config file with a list of files to ignore (or the windoze equivilent) or you can edit the properties of the directory the file is in with a svn ignore.

See his post on how to do ignores: [How do I ignore a directory with SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn)

I am sure tortoise has a way to right click edit ignore property for a file... Check this--i found it by googling 'svn ignore files tortiose'

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html

Answer (score 2):

Use SVN properties, in particular you'll be interested in svn:ignore.

Using TortoiseSVN this is easy. In your working copy, simply right-click on the file to ignore (donotupdateme.txt) select TortoiseSVN -> Unversion and add to ignore list -> donotupdatme.txt.

This will prevent the file from being committed/updated.

Check out http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html for more details on this.

Hope this helps!