# How to ignore directories/files in Subversion?

Tags: java, linux, spring, svn, maven

How to setup my Subversion so it ignores target files generated by Maven on Linux? I don't want to commit them into SVN.

How do I do this on Linux and Mac command line?

Comment: right.. how do I set that up so the comment does not checkin my target

Comment: what have you tried? Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To ignore files in subversion you want to set the svn:ignore property.  You can see more here http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html about half way down.

To ignore the target folder from your project folder run

```
svn propset svn:ignore target .
```

Alternatively to edit a list of ignored files folders run

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

Answer (score 10):

Before committing code to the Subversion repository we always set the svn:ignore property on the directory to prevent some files and directories to be checked in. We always exclude the IDE project files and the target/ directory. Instead of keeping all of the excludes in mind all the time it's useful to put them all in a file and reference the file with the -F option:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .
```

Put this file in the project folder

```
.svnignore
target/*
```

Comment: can you give me a list of files you added

Comment: is there one file in root of project (/.svnignore )  or we must set it for each Subproject in svn ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `svn propset`:

```
svn propset svn:ignore directory .
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a simple way that you can add it to svn:ignore in eclipse IDE after adding the target folder to revision and then restoring it.

Comment: If you use eclipse you should add the folder to "ignored resources" (window > preferences > team > ignore resources)!