# How to exclude a certain type of files during checkout in Jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I want to exclude *.zip , *.xls ,*.pdf , *.doc , *.exe ... during the checkout using SVN in Jenkins.

Comment: Do you want to avoid triggering a build if a `.doc` file changes, or do you want the `.doc` file to not show up in the Jenkins workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **Excluded Regions**? You can find the settings if you click **Advanced...** in the SVN configuration section.

> If set, and Jenkins is set to poll for changes, Jenkins will ignore
>   any files and/or folders in this list when determining if a build
>   needs to be triggered.
>
> Each exclusion uses regular expression pattern matching, and must be
>   separated by a new line.
>
> ```
> /trunk/myapp/src/main/web/.*\.html
> /trunk/myapp/src/main/web/.*\.jpeg
> /trunk/myapp/src/main/web/.*\.gif
> ```
>
> The example above illustrates that if only html/jpeg/gif files have
>   been committed to the SCM a build will not occur.

Comment: I have scheduled jobs on Jenkins  , POLL is not checked !  SO the first time when i check out the project how do i exclude these unwanted files ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SVN 1.5 on the server, or higher, you can use **[Sparse-checkouts](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.5.html#sparse-checkouts)**, but that would only help you if all the files that are you want excluded are organized into their own folders.

Really, SVN is not supposed to be storing .exe files (as those are considered artifacts, that can be built from source). Maybe what you need is [`svn:ignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn) property, to avoid those files being checked in in the first place