# Prevent a complete directory from being commited ins subversion in netbeans 7.2

Tags: svn, netbeans-7

I am trying to exclude a folder from commit in project directory but it still shows up in the list of files and folders to b committed. I right click on the folder Subversion->exclude from commit but still it shows up. I have tried `svn:ignore` but it does not ignore directories.

Answer (score 0):

`svn:ignore` does works on directories AFAIK. But It won't work if the directory is alreay under source control

from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn)

> Note: This won't work if the directory is already "in" svn. `svn rm
>   --keep-local dirname` first. (My svn stat output was huge and I bumped my head into this for a while.) – Erik Aronesty