# Eclipse .settings folder and .project file location

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I have huge maven project with a lot of modules and using intellij IDEA for coding and eclipse for formatting the code and using SVN as VCS. So eclipse creates these .settings folders and .project files and makes a mess in the project folder.
What I'm trying to achieve is to move these .project's and .settings's to some other location not to have these in the intellij idea file tree and not to have it tracked in the SVN.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can make svn ignore those files, try `svn propset svn:ignore *.settings .` fro mthe root folder of your project - mind the dot - it is the directory the property is set on.

Comment: and see this question for a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn

Answer (score 4):

Invert your thinking. Create the Eclipse project at a location where the presence of Eclipse metadata files isn't going to bother you. Then link your source directories into the project.

New -> Folder -> Advanced -> Link to an alternate location