# Can I prevent folder/files from updating and committing in my SVN repository?

Tags: svn, repository

In Android development there are some folder with files that are generated when the build is run and don't need to be included in our repository since they differ between the developers.

Can I tell the repository to not include and/or stop including the folder tree in the update/delete commands?

Comment: [Possible duplicate "How to ignore a directory with SVN?".](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  [SVN's excellent documentation tells you how](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html).

Assuming you're using TortiseSVN, the instructions are listed at the link above.  Excerpt:

> In most projects you will have files and folders that should not be
>   subject to version control. These might include files created by the
>   compiler, *.obj, *.lst, maybe an output folder used to store the
>   executable. Whenever you commit changes, TortoiseSVN shows your
>   unversioned files, which fills up the file list in the commit dialog.
>   Of course you can turn off this display, but then you might forget to
>   add a new source file.
>
> The best way to avoid these problems is to add the derived files to
>   the project's ignore list. That way they will never show up in the
>   commit dialog, but genuine unversioned source files will still be
>   flagged up.
>
> If you right click on a single unversioned file, and select the
>   command TortoiseSVN → Add to Ignore List from the context menu, a
>   submenu appears allowing you to select just that file, or all files
>   with the same extension. Both submenus also have a (recursively)
>   equivalent. If you select multiple files, there is no submenu and you
>   can only add those specific files/folders.
>
> If you choose the (recursively) version of the ignore context menu,
>   the item will be ignored not just for the selected folder but all
>   subfolders as well. However this requires SVN clients version 1.8 or
>   higher.
>
> If you want to remove one or more items from the ignore list, right
>   click on those items and select TortoiseSVN → Remove from Ignore List
>   You can also access a folder's svn:ignore property directly. That
>   allows you to specify more general patterns using filename globbing,
>   described in the section below. Read the section called “Project
>   Settings” for more information on setting properties directly. Please
>   be aware that each ignore pattern has to be placed on a separate line.
>   Separating them by spaces does not work.

If you're not using Tortoise, you can look in the [SVN-book.red-bean.com documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Comment: I'm not using Tortoise, so is there a command I should review in the link provided?

Comment: Sort of.  There are instructions for setting the configuration.  Click on the svn-book link at the bottom of the answer. Choose which version you wish to open.  (Html single page, html multiple pages, pdf, etc.) and look for "ignoring un-versioned items".