# Svn Status -u and ignore files from specific directory

Tags: svn, svn-update

i am running a command SVN STATUS -U, and now i want it to bring all the changes except  /temporary folder.
I don't have any idea how can i do this?
Because i don't want to see all entries of /temporary folder when i run svn status -u (hundreds of files added in temp directory on server, and it brings lot of entries when executing the command)

I am using putty after logging via SSH.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore a directory with SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn)

Comment: `svn st -u | grep -v temporary`

Comment: But better solution will be ignore all content of folder with svn:ignore **AND** unversion already versioned /temporary shit

Answer (score 0):

You could add the files in `/temporary` to the `svn:ignore` property of `/temporary`:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*" path/to/temporary
```

That, however, will also keep the files in `/temporary` from being tracked by svn (they are ignored, after all), so if this is not what you want, please be more specific.

Comment: i executed this and get this error, [root@server latest]# svn propset svn:ignore "*" /temporary
svn: warning: cannot set LC_CTYPE locale
svn: warning: environment variable LC_CTYPE is UTF-8
svn: warning: please check that your locale name is correct
svn: '/' is not a working copy

Comment: You need to provide the actual path to the `/temporary` directory in your working copy/repository. If you just write `/temporary` it will look for a folder named `temporary` at the root of your filesystem!

Comment: Ok i executed this command: svn propset svn:ignore "*" /var/www/vhosts/abc/latest/temporary       and it shows me this output       


property 'svn:ignore' set on '/var/www/vhosts/abc/latest/temporary'            but when i executed svn status -u, it again showing me entries from /temporary direcotry

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **Sometimes it is desirable to have files that reside in a repository that you do not want overwritten in your workspace** in a similar fashion to the way Subversion can ignore files that you commit.  Config files with your local settings are an example where you would want files ignored during updates.

**Subversion does not have this feature.**  The answers that "work" that I have seen over the years are:

- **write a script that updates the individual files** and/or directories and ignores the files and/or directories that you want left alone (tedious)
- **remove the files or directories from subversion** and then obviously they are not there to overwrite your files (seems sketchy to me)

---

Mark