# svn project from different directories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Good day.
Question is simple, but I haven't found a proper answer for it so far...

Let's say I have Joomla site (doesn't matter though), which consists of many folders and files. And in it I have a project, that consists of a component, and a module.
So, in order to track them as one project I need to put

```
www/site1/comonents/com_component1/*
www/site1/modules/mod_module1/*
www/site1/translations/en-EN/en-EN.com_component1.ini
```

in one folder in SVN, but ommit everything else.

Any advices of where to read (preferrably with exact directions for chapters) would be appreciated. As well as any ready solution :)

Thanks for your time anyways.

Comment: p.s. using tortoisesvn, installed on CentOS, managed on Windows (that's my machine). Mainly I do things in UI, not in CLI :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore a directory with SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn)

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think so. In my case I would need ignore on parent folder, but  include on SOME childs. In other words - thats a tonn of work, to put all ignores on place, and I'm not that sure if it will work, needs testing. But - that's at least a way. Thanks :) Will test tomorrow.

Comment: Actually, I don't see a question at all.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a problem (and question, BTW) here. What is **exactly** your problem:

- How to deploy `<some objects>` into existing tree?
- (partially related to above) How to build proper repository tree?
- How to combine repository with CMS (out of your responsibility) with repository of your development?

Answer on 1 is question of deploy tools used, unrelated to SVN

Answer on 2 may be repository-tree like

```
components/com_component1/
modules/mod_module1/
translations/en-EN/en-EN.com_component1.ini
```

and known for deploy tool mapping between repository-paths and site-paths (for SVN-hooks you can store this mapping as SVN-properties of directories with special name)

Answer on 3 may be SVN externals

Comment: No problems bro ) I am just searching for a convenient solution of 1 and 2 problems you've mentioned, so that it would really be seamless and easy-to-use, and easily copied by my team.

Really helpful answer, gave some ideas.

Got distracted by real life (marriage of a friend), but - will start trying those ideas whenever back in lab. Thanks.