# Conditionally ignore path from Subversion?

Tags: angularjs, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

Is it possible to globally ignore a folder IF it is a child of a folder having a specific name?  For example...

Exclude:

```
client/vendor
```

... or ...

```
app/vendor
```

But never exclude a "vendor" folder if it appears anywhere else?

I'm working on an AngularJS project and the "vendor" folder is common for client-side files.  However, theoretically, it is possible that "vendor" may have another meaning in future projects and, if it does, it would generally be in another path.

The docs on this are a bit misleading (to me, anyway).  It says to use the svn:ignore property but no examples anywhere show how to specify the conditional parent folder.  They all appear to be manually ignoring a specific folder every time... via a command line.

Per the TortoiseSVN docs:

> **No Paths in Global Ignore List** [(Link here)](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html)
>  You should not include
>   path information in your pattern. The pattern matching is intended to
>   be used against plain file names and folder names. If you want to
>   ignore all CVS folders, just add CVS to the ignore list. There is no
>   need to specify CVS */CVS as you did in earlier versions. If you want
>   to ignore all tmp folders when they exist within a prog folder but not
>   within a doc folder you should use the svn:ignore property instead.
>   There is no reliable way to achieve this using global ignore patterns.

Comment: I found that: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice find, David!  Thanks.  :)