# Is it necessary to upload all of the Laravel framework to hosting for each project?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel framework for a small project. It's difficult to commit files to SVN couse 'svn status' command shows cache files and other files used for the framework with files created for me. The questions is if it's necessary to upload to all of those Laravel framework files? I mean Laravel is huge! Or what is the best practice when I'm implementing Laravel with a new project? I'm new with this technology.

Comment: See [how to ignore files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-with-svn) from SVN.

Answer (score 0):

for as far as my understanding of the laravel framework goes, most of the files are linked to each other in one way or another, making it almost impossible to delete unneeded/unwanted features without a whole lot of tweaking