# wso2 svn synchronizer upload to -1234

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

We're working with SVN synchronizer on our WSO2 AM-1.10.0.

We noticed that for the super admin directory (-1234) it attempts to load thousands of files, most of them we are not even sure we need to commit (for example: jaggeryapps, etc - we do not need them to be shared).

In general, we're only interested in sharing the tenants info, to allow gateway nodes on the cluster to run API's created at the manager node).

As our SVN is in SaaS that has a limit of 5000 files per commit, we're getting error message on this and the -1234 commit fails.

Is there a way to filter out the files WSO2 attempts to commit to SVN server from the -1234 directory? How can we configure it to commit only the minumum required set of files?

Comment: Have you tried svn ignore directory? 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/116075/1008424

Comment: Note that the files are not yet in SVN. It is WSO2 synchronizer who tries to commit them to SVN and fails. So I have to tell WSO2 to leave them away not trying to commit, rather than tell SVN about a directory already committed which should be ignored.

Comment: You can add svn ignore file to repository/deployment/server path before starting the pack.