# SVN: Ignore some directories recursively

Tags: svn, version-control, ignore

I don't want any directory named `build` or `dist` to go into my SVN no matter how deep in the tree it is.

Is this possible? In git I just put

```
build
dist
```

in my `.gitignore` at the root and it recursively ignores. How do I do this with svn? Please don't tell me to do a propset on every parent dir...

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28425994/971090) for a native solution if you're using Subversion 1.8.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As of subversion 1.8, there is now the `svn:global-ignores` property which works like `svn:ignore` but recursively (so set this on your top-level directory)

Comment: I'm a tad confused - there's `global-ignores` in the `~/.subversion/config` file, but also the *inheritable* `svn:global-ignores` property set on a directory in an SVN repo, as well as `svn:ignore` - can you provide a summary of these different options and how they compare? How does the `--recursive` flag affect them too?

Comment: I've done my own research and published my findings in this QA answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/86052/159145

Comment: [I've tried but failed, the `obj` folder still showed up] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960188/svnglobal-ignores-not-working), can you help me to have a look on it?

Comment: Can I say "build/*" go ignore everything below build within every build folder?

Comment: This won't ignore folder by name recursively on svn version 1.14.0 (r1876290).

Answer (score 44):

`svn propset` takes `--recursive` as an option, so you can do this, with two downsides:

1. you have to check out the entire repository (or at least all directories therein), and
2. you have to remember to set the `svn:ignore` property whenever you add a new directory

Answer (score 17):

This works for me:

```
 svn propset --recursive svn:ignore *.zip <dir_tree_with_no_zips>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, works great...By the way the only way I found to ignore both *.txt and *.pdf was to put those patterns in a file and then use the 'svn propset --file' option

Answer (score 15):

add to your ~/.subversion/config or /etc/subversion/config file:

```
[miscellany]
global-ignores = build dist
```

Comment: I'd rather do it per-repo if I can

Comment: hmm not sure if there's an easy way to do it per-repo, a pre-commit hook could reject certain patterns, but it's not a complete solution. svn:ignore on each parent dir works, but not recursively. you could swap out your config file with a script when working on different repos, but that's an extra step.

Comment: What does **build dist** mean?

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to ignore build and dist dirs by removing the directories from version control.  The trick is to use the --keep-local option to leave the directory in the working copy.  For example:

```
svn rm dist --keep-local
svn ci -m'removed build directory from version control'
```

The directory will no longer be tracked by subversion but it will still be there in your working copy to hold compiler output, etc.

cheers,
joe

Comment: This solution looks similar to `git ignore`.

Answer (score 7):

In subversion 1.8 over, it is possible to set global-ignores for current repository.

```
svn propset svn:global-ignores build .
svn propset svn:global-ignores dist .
```

Also you can create a folder named .svnignore, and write conditions.

```
build
dist
```

remember one condition per line, setting build/* or dist/debug is in vain. 
Then do the command:

```
svn propset svn:global-ignores -F .svnignore .
```

Comment: works flawlessly! just run the first command on newly checked out repo.

Answer (score 6):

For example the folder structure:

```
Project/
Project/dist/

cd Project
svn propset svn:ignore '*' dist/
svn ci -m "content of dist ignored"
```

It's good to do a svn delete of dist content before the ignore command, so for branches dist will be empty.

Worked for me, tested today.
[Here is the page explaining it a bit](http://www.heavymind.net/2007/08/29/the-nightmare-has-returned-with-new-name-svnignore/)

Answer (score 5):

In order to ignore all such files in all repositories, you could add a `global-ignores` to your per-user configuration file.

> On Unix-like systems, this area
>   appears as a directory named
>   .subversion in the user's home
>   directory. On Win32 systems,
>   Subversion creates a folder named
>   Subversion, typically inside the
>   Application Data area of the user's
>   profile directory

See [Configuration Options](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1.3)

Unfortunately, there's no per-repository option to do this. It's basically per-user, or per-directory, so the multiple `svn:ignores` is probably the way to go, as annoying as it can be.

Comment: I'd rather do it per-repo if i can

Comment: Oh, then you're out of luck. As @Kevin Reid says - you've got per-directory or per-user.

Answer (score 5):

You first have to move to the top folder of your working copy and create a file there (say .svnignore) where you should place all the patterns that you want to be ignored, for example (for an Android project):

```
bin
gen
proguard
.classpath
.project
local.properties
Thumbs.db
*.apk
*.ap_
*.class
*.dex
```

Then you run the following command (remember that you must be at the top folder of your working copy):

```
svn propset svn:ignore -R -F .svnignore .
```

This will only work for folders and files that are not yet under version control. If you want a folder (or file) that is being versioned to start being ignored as well, remove it from version control by running the command:

```
svn rm --keep-local <path>
```

Got all this from this great article that explains it all: http://superchlorine.com/2013/08/getting-svn-to-ignore-files-and-directories/

Comment: This was immensely helpful. This is the best way I've found to get git-like ignore behavior in svn. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file and add your ignores into it

ingore-list:

```
file1 
directory1
file2
etc...
```

then apply the following command

```
for n in directory; do svn propset svn:ignore -F ignore-list $n; done
```

directory is name of your directory, you can sub categorize as well  directory/sub-directory.  Or use * to note current directory you are under.

This is assuming you are using bash as your shell

Comment: What is the **$n** here?

Comment: @igor Ganapolsky  - The $n is the variable of the for loop.  It will be set as the index for the sequence you are looping into; in this case the directory as specified by "directory" in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn propset --recursive svn:ignore svn_ignore_rules .
```

where svn_ignore_rules is a file containing the ignore rules -- one per line

Of course you have to re-run it every time you add a new directory to your repo

svn_ignore_rules can also be considered to be checked into the repo, to be re-useable by other users having write access to the repo

Answer (score 1):

```
cd parent_dir #the directory containing folder to be ignored recursively
svn propedit svn:ignore . #will open up svn-prop.tmp
enlist folder(s)
^X
Y
commit -m 'ignore targeted direcoty'
```

Comment: helped me, I had problem with setting folder pattern, SVN was complianing that folder not in repo, `set  EDITOR=notepad`, `svn propedit svn:ignore .`worked well...

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add some kind of check to either the pre- or post- commit hook but it's note straight forward if you don't own the repo server.

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems to be no solution for this probably common problem, i would like to share our solution. As the others already made clear, you can either use the `svn:ignore` property, this applies to a single directory (and therefore not for new ones), or you use `global-ignores` which applies to a single user (but doesn't belong to the repository).

To make life a bit easier i created a reg file named `Settings.Svn.reg` and added it to the root of the repository. Now everybody can doublecklick this regfile once, and has the settings done.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config\miscellany]
"global-ignores"="obj *.suo *.bak *.pdb *.user *.Cache*"
```

I would really appreciate a solution within the SVN repository, so if somebody knows, would you care to share it?