# Is there a concept of global ignores in svn?

Tags: svn, svnignore

Is there a way to setup a global list of Ignores for a SVN Repository or for the SVN Client on the PC?

The only reason I'm using tools like Tortoise/Ankh/VisualSVN is because I want to only check in the files I need without all the bin/obj/Resharper stuff.

I'm spoiled by `.gitignore` and `.hgignore` which I just copy to a repository and then use `git commit -a` without having to care about checking in junk.

I know I can manually set it, but that's tedious to do and I think it had to be applied to every new folder that gets created as well.

Using SVN under Windows.

Comment: While the accepted answer is valid, bahrep's answer is what the OP was asking for and is a better workflow. Please check out his answer instead of doing this locally.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `svn propset svn:ignore "*.myextension" .` command?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, I think it should be rather `svn propset --recursive svn:ignore "*.myextension" .`. However, such ignore will not apply for new folders which are created afterwards. Use `svn:global-ignores` for general ignore.

Comment: See also [How do I ignore files in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion) which has answers for global ignores.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

On an install of Subversion, there is a file in a path such as one of the following:

- Windows Vista/7/8/8.1/10: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config`
- Windows XP: `c:\Documents and Settings\<username>\.subversion\config`
- Unix (Linux, etc), macOS: `$HOME/.subversion/config`

that contains a global configuration for Subversion. In the `[miscellany]` section is a `global-ignores` parameter which you can use to set up globally ignored filename patterns.

The [Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html) section of the Subversion book has more information, including how to set up such global configuration parameters in the registry if you need to.

### Typical examples:

```
[miscellany]
global-ignores = *.o *.so *.so.[0-9]* .DS_Store [Tt]humbs.db
```

or perhaps if you are in a transition phase to using Git:

```
[miscellany]
global-ignores = .git
```

Comment: It's in %AppData%\Subversion for me.

Comment: Cool, that works. I'd still prefer per repository, but this doesn't require propedit so it's better IMHO.

Comment: It's possible to use `svn:global-ignores` property on repository side if you use Subversion 1.8 client: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config

Comment: ~/.subversion/config or /etc/subversion/config

for Mac/Linux

and

%appdata%\subversion\config

for Windows

Comment: Could only find it under `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion`.

Comment: Windows Vista/7/8/8.1/10: `%appdata%\subversion\config`

Answer (score 43):

It is **possible to setup global ignores in a repository** if you use Subversion 1.8 and newer client.

Subversion 1.8 release introduced the [Repository Dictated Configuration](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config) feature. Thanks to this new feature, you can configure the `svn:global-ignores` property on repository side.

See [SVNBook 1.8 | Ignoring Unversioned Items](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) and [SVNBook 1.8 | Inherited properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.inheritable) for more information.

Comment: For usage example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33684419/79125).