# SVN Ignore files anywhere in project

Tags: svn, svnignore

so I have started using Subversion and am confused about the ignore files.

From what I've read, I can ignore files within a directory with propedit/propset. However, I added a rule to ignore files starting with a dot (swap files for VIM which sometimes get left over), but it would seem then that I would have to apply that rule to every single directory and subdirectory in the project.

Does anyone know a way to make a file-pattern ignore statement work recursively using SVN?

here's my super-simple ignore (I'm assuming SVN uses GLOB and not RE):

```
.*
```

and my project is something like:

```
project/
  application/
     models/
     views/
        form1/
        form2/
     config/
     controllers/ 
     libraries/
     plugins/
     helpers/
  css/
```

and many of the folders under application are several levels deep. It would be a supreme annoyance to have to apply this rule to each and every folder, especially since this is under active development and subject to change.

ALSO, i should add that I am NOT interested in modifying my user subversion config in ~/.subversion/ because I want this ignore to live in the repository, and affect all developers, not just me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use `svn propset --recursive svn:ignore .*` from the root of your project.

Comment: Indeed. Exactly what I needed. It also behaves properly when a new folder is created with a file starting with a dot, perfetto!

Comment: @Kasapo: It's considered as good style to accept the answer if your satisfied. Upvoting as well shows real appreciation.

Comment: Ahh, there we go. I think I accepted it now. As I am a new member, I cannot upvote it, but I do thank you for your quick answer, while I found a lot of doc that *almost* had the answer, this is what I needed.

Comment: I accidentally ran your whole command even though I didn't want to ignore .*.  How would I undo this?

Comment: @Greg: I believe `svn propedit ignore .*` would take you in to an editor to remove the ignore. Check http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.propedit.html , but I'm pretty sure that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the propset --recursive option actually sets the properties recursively, but does not permanently/globally ignore the files. You can globally ignore by updating your .subversion/config file, and this will ignore the pattern everywhere regardless of where the files are located and svn props on individual files/folders.

See this stackoverflow discussion: [Is there a concept of global ignores in svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694900/global-ignores-for-svn)