# svn ignore unversioned files in subdirectories

Tags: svn

I am trying set the svn:global-ignores property for several unversioned files that exist in subdirectories.

If I run

`svn propset svn:global-ignores dir/ignore-me.txt .`

then `svn st dir/ignore-me.txt` still indicates the file is unversioned with a question mark.

But If I cd into that directory first, then

`svn propset svn:global ignores ignore-me.txt .`

results in that file being correctly ignored (The status is "I" when I run `svn st dir/ignore-me.txt`.

What is going on here? I see this behavior whether I ignore files individually or whether I ignore a list of files stored in a text doc. Why do I need to cd into a directory just to ignore a file?

Comment: Are you trying to ignore files in a specific folder only? Please describe your use case.

Comment: I have a text file called .svnignore-list containing hundreds of paths to files I want to ignore (mostly autogenerated code), spread among many subdirectories. I have tried running "svn propset svn:global-ignores -F .svnignore-list ." but this does not result in any of those files being ignored.

Comment: `global-ignores` is a configuration option (not a property). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694900/is-there-a-concept-of-global-ignores-in-svn#2694934) for how to set it.