# Commit ignore files/dires to remote repo

Tags: svn

```
Linux Mint 20.3
Java 11
SVN 1.14
```

In my java project to ignore some files/dirs I use the next command:

```
svn propset svn:ignore *.class .
```

Ignore all class files in my Java project.

Nice. It's work fine. But it ignore only local. I need to commit ignores to remote repo.
So after I delete my local project folder and get latest version by this:

```
svn checkout some_url_here
```

Then to be ignore all files/dirs that I added by first command.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It is described in numerous other posts on StackOverflow and in the documentation. If other answers don’t help, then you need to elaborate your question.

Comment: [svn propget](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.propget.html) does not set the value, it only reads it. And there isn't such a thing as local or remote repositories; unlike git, Subversion is a centralised version control system.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I was updated my post

Comment: "I need to commit ignores to remote repo". Correct. Are you asking about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694900/is-there-a-concept-of-global-ignores-in-svn/20497866