# Append directories to ignored list in SVN

Tags: svn

I have a big directories tree involving many subdirectories. In many of the directories I used the `svn propedit svn:ignore .`, and ignored files and/or directories in the given directory. Now, I want to ignore, in *all* subdirectories the directories called `foo`. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9211176/671013), it is suggested to invoke:

```
svn propset --recursive svn:ignore foo .
```

from the tree's root. The problem is, that once invoking this, it overrides all predefined ignores in the various subdirectories - and this is undesired. Essentially I would like to append to the ignore list of each directory in the tree, a line with entry `foo` in it. **Does SVN supports this kind of action?** If not, then I was thinking of scripting this task, and add to the file `dir-prop-base` (which seems to hold the ignore list) in each `./sub/directory/.svn` (where `.` is the tree's root) the needed line. **Is it safe to do it?**, namely manually mess with `.svn` content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using a bash script for this task. But instead of manipulating the files directly, stay with the *svn command tools*. This solution is simple and safe. The following script might do the job, if executed with `find -type d ! -path "*/.svn*" -exec /tmp/add_svn_ignore.sh {} +` from the working directory:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
ignore="foo"
for pathname in "$@"; do
    lines="$( svn propget svn:ignore "$pathname" )"
    grep -F -x -q "$ignore" - <<< "$lines" ||
    svn propset svn:ignore "$lines"$'\n'"$ignore" "$pathname"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it and it seems like the `find` command you suggested is wrong, I get `find: illegal option` error for each letter of "type" and finally `find: d: No such file or directory`. I'm using OS X in case it matters. Thanks again.

Comment: I am using _GNU find_. On OS X, _find_ requires a path before the first option. Try `find . -type d ...` instead of `find -type d ...`.