# Append directories to ignored list in svn (Windows)

Tags: bash, svn, vbscript, scripting, ignore

There once was almost the [same question]: [Append directories to ignored list in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648586/append-directories-to-ignored-list-in-svn) that I'm asking, but I'm needing it for windows.

For my needs, I need a script like @nosid wrote in that thread:

```
#! /bin/bash
ignore="foo"
for pathname in "$@"; do
    lines="$( svn propget svn:ignore "$pathname" )"
    grep -F -x -q "$ignore" - <<< "$lines" ||
    svn propset svn:ignore "$lines"$'\n'"$ignore" "$pathname"
done
```

**Do you know how to implement that with vbscript (or batch)?**

At the moment I'm doing it like this and this just unversions WimID.xml but all other ignored files aren't ignored anymore ([Ignore file in Subversion removes old values from svn:ignore property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856458/ignore-file-in-subversion-removes-old-values-from-svnignore-property)).

```
fso.MoveFile "G:\x\BuildImage\WimID.xml", "G:\WimID.xml"

wshshell.run UnversionBat

fso.MoveFile "G:\WimID.xml", "G:\x\BuildImage\WimID.xml"
```

The UnversionBat is:

```
svn commit WimID.xml -m "test"

svn propset svn:ignore WimID.xml .
```

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript you'd loop over the argument list like this:

```vbs
For Each pathname In WScript.Arguments
  ...
Next
```

The output of an external command can be read like this:

```vbs
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set svn = sh.Exec("svn propget svn:ignore """ & pathname & """")
Do While svn.Status = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
If svn.ExitCode = 0 Then lines = Split(svn.StdOut.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
```

For running an external command without reading its output you can use either the [`Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) or the [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it as follow: `For Each sPath In WScript.Arguments Set svn = wshshell.Exec("svn propget svn:ignore """ & sPath & """") Do While svn.Status = 0 WScript.Sleep 100 Loop If svn.ExitCode = 0 Then lines = Split(svn.StdOut.ReadAll, vbNewLine) Next MsgBox lines` sPath is a directory which has six ignored files in it, so shouldn't the MsgBox give me the names of these six files? What am I doing wrong? I don't really get what's Wscript.Arguments for. I just want to ignore one more file in a specific path, so when I can read out the old ones, I can just add them again.

Comment: I was able to make it loop through all files in a specific folder but it still shows me nothing: 
`Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(sPath)

For Each File In objFolder.Files
  
  MsgBox File
  
 Set svn = wshshell.Exec("svn propget svn:ignore """ & File & """")
 Do While svn.Status = 0
   WScript.Sleep 100
 Loop
 If svn.ExitCode = 0 Then lines = Split(svn.StdOut.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
 
Next` What could be the problem?

Comment: Does the command work when you run it directly in `CMD`? Property names are case-sensitive, so, is the name spelled correctly? Do you get output on STDERR (`WScript.Echo svn.StdErr.ReadAll`)?

Comment: When I run `svn propget svn:ignore G:\depot\stage2\BuildImage\WimID.xml` (WimID.xml is ignored atm) directly in `CMD` I get that it isn't under version control. When I run it on a file that is under version control, I don't get an output at all. The name is spelled correctly. Output on STDERR is only the last file in the directory WimID.xml: `svn: E200005: G:\depot\stage2\BuildImage\WimID.xml isn't under version control` then the output of lines is empty.

Comment: Well, version control doesn't control files that aren't under version control, so there's nothing for `svn` to handle there. If the command doesn't produce output on STDOUT that means that either an error occurred (in which case there should be output on STDERR) or that the file doesn't have the specified property.