# svn:global-ignores not working?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

I've added bin obj to my root folders
But when I Check for modifications, the obj folder still show up.
What happen and what I can do for make it ignore bin & obj folder recursively for all my workingcopy?
I'm using **svn version 1.10.0-dev** with **TortoiseSVN 1.10.0, Build 28176 - 64Bit, 2018/04/14 08:00:32** on Windows 10 64bit.

[image: I've added bin obj to my root folders]
[image: obj folder show up]
[image: version]

Comment: Can you please indicate your version of Subversion and TortoiseSVN ?

Comment: @LaurentH. I'm using `svn, version 1.10.0-dev` with `TortoiseSVN 1.10.0, Build 28176 - 64 Bit , 2018/04/14 08:00:32` on Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

The subversion `global-ignores` contains collection of file patterns.

**The subversion client checks these patterns agains the names of the files that are candidates for addition to the version control and unversioned files.**

In your case if you are still seeing the files bin and object files in your root folder at the repository(not the working copy). This means you have added them to version control and after successful addition to version control you have added these patterns of bin and obj to the `global-ignores` list.

Now you would need to manually un-versioned them first and then do your normal commits and the files with the pattern bin and obj will not be added.

Comment: It's not like your description. the `/DataEntryDAL/obj` has been just created after set `global-ignores`