# How can I add and ignore in subversion?

Tags: svn

For example suppose I have a directory 'project' but I want to ignore anything matching the following wildcard '*.jpg' when I add the directory.  How can I do this?

Edit: To clarify I'm running into a chicken and egg problem.  I can't ignore files before I have added a directory to version control.  However once I add the directory it adds automatically the files I wish to ignore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I ignore files in subversion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Subversion configuration file. On Unix/Mac/Linux systems, it's `$HOME/.subversion/config`. In Windows, it can be different places. Normally it's in `%USERPROFILE%\.subversion\config`, but I can't vouch for it on every system. Some Subversion client might put it in the registry.

In the Subversion configuration file, there's a section `[miscellany]`. A few lines down, there's a `global-ignores` entry. Any file that matches the glob patterns won't be added by a recursive `svn add` or an `svn add` with a file globbing pattern instead of a specific file name. Also, any non-added file that matches the globbing pattern won't show up when you do an `svn status` by default.

See [this section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config) in the Subversion online manual. Take a look about the `global-ignores`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the svn:ignore property

```
> svn pe . svn:ignore
```

This should open up your default text editor. Add the following:-

```
*.jpg
```

Then save and commit.

See [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) for more details.