# SVN ignore files

Tags: svn

I'm trying to ignore the file `img/test.jpg` from being followed by SVN. Prompted by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion) I have tried the command:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "img/test.jpg" .
```

Instead of ignoring `img/test.jpg`, SVN tells me `property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'`.

Also, when I do `svn status` I now get the extra line:

```
 M      .
```

How can have SVN ignore a file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Despite confusing output, your command appears to have worked correctly.  The line

```
M    .
```

...indicates that you have set a property on the current directory (the one you ran the command from). The ignored path is `./img/test.jpg`, but the property is set on the current directory rather than the specific file. It has a modified flag `M` because you have yet to commit the property back to the repository. After you commit this, subsequent checkouts or others working on this codebase after `svn update` will also get the `svn:ignore` property on that file.

Note: To modify or remove this via `svn propdel`, you would need to do so from the current directory as well:

```
svn propdel svn:ignore .
```

You could have also `cd`'ed into the `img/` directory and run the `propset` in there, in which case it would be bound to that directory rather than its parent. Your commit would then look something like:

```
M    img
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the property on the `img` directory, not the root:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "test.jpg" img
```

Comment: OP **can** use any directory in the tree below file-to-be-ignored as mount-point and relative path to file in definition

Comment: @LazyBadger This does not work for me. I have a file in a subdirectory, call `svn propset svn:ignore "folder\file.txt" .`. Then I see `M .` like mentioned. However, after committing `.`, `svn st` still shows the file under `folder\file.txt`. However, the solution I suggested, works for me.

Comment: 1. You **can't ignore already versioned** file, only "unknown" 2. You **must to re-read** SVN-Book

Comment: @LazyBadger The file.txt in my example was unversioned. I copied the example to pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/ay4nB2vj). Could you please explain, why the referencing via 'subfolder' does not work and the direct change of the _img_ directory does. Thanks.