# SVN status and ignore a folder

Tags: svn, svnignore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ignore a directory with SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn)

I am trying to do an svn status to see the files I have not commited, however there is a folder called 'phpunit' and I would like to ignore that folder, is this possible?

Thanks,
J

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion

Comment: I am not sure if I understand would I do something like this: `svn status svn:ignore 'phpunit'` I tried that but it ignored all my files except for the files inside phpunit

Comment: No, like this: `svn propset svn:ignore phpunit` (`propset` instead of `status`).

Comment: I tried that and got this error `Explicit target required ('phpunit' interpreted as prop value)`

Comment: Don't forget the dot in the end of the command line

Comment: I tried it with the dot and got this message `property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'`

Answer (score 3):

See SVNBook article ["Ignoring Unversioned Items"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html).

The command you look for:
`svn propset svn:ignore "phpunit" .`

See [`svn propset` reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html).

Comment: I tried that and got this message `property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'`

Comment: Per the documentation @bahrep linked, this is what you should have been expecting