# Test results of svn:ignore without commit

Tags: svn, ignore, svnignore

Is there a way to test the results of the svn:ignore property without doing a commit first?

I have a large svn project that I reorganized locally using git.  Now I need to apply the svn:ignore property to match the .gitignore file.  I'd like to test that all my changes to the svn:ignore property work properly before I do a commit.  Is there a way to do this?

I know could work on a branch until I get it right and then merge, but it seems there should be an easier way.

Comment: Use `svn status`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion

Comment: `svn status` does not look at local changes to properties (that I am aware of).  I would have to commit, which is what I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your `svn:ignore` before you commit your change with the `svn:ignore` property. Create files and/or directories to be ignored. Don't do a `svn add`. Just add the files to your working directory.

Then, do a `svn ignore`. Those files added to your working directory should not show up. (REMEMBER: Don't do `svn add` for these files!). After that, you can do a `svn status --no-ignore` and the files being ignored should show up with a status of `I`.

I find it easier to set your `VISUAL` environment variable, and then use `svn pe svn:ignore` since each ignored file specification should be on its own line.

Remember, if a file is already in your repository, it cannot be ignored.

Comment: Some of the differences between what works with .gitignore and svn:ignore were tripping me up and made it appear as though it wasn't working, but the `--no-ignore` option got me back on the right track.