# Don't want to store all of Zend in SVN

Tags: php, apache, svn, zend-framework

I want to svn my zend project but not the whole Zend framework but not sure how.

I want to have just these directories in SVN

--application
--library
--public

but the rest of the framework and files maybe n /var/shared or seomthing.

How do I link my project to the framework so I can just check it out to my /var/www/html directory and it just works?

Comment: Most use composer for this, so you have a composer file in your svn and then someone else can get the composer file and run it and get the zend librarie.

Comment: You're asking about Dependency Management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add: SetEnv ZF2_PATH "/path/to/zf2/library" in your virtualhost configuration. If you set this enviroment variable, then you dont need store zend libs in your project :P

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) to manage your project dependencies and add Zend to [svn:ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion).

Take a look at: [using Composer with ZF](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer). The package `zendframework/zendframework` is probably what you want.