# How to filter out unwanted files while committing to SVN?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I have a Delphi XE4 project folder say MyProject. In MyProject folder, there are some files which are changed automatically when I compile the project and I need not to check in those files.

For example: `.drc, .exe, .identcache, .local, .map, .res, .vrc`

Whenever I right click MyProject and press Commit, I want these files should not appear in the list of modified files. How can I get this filter in SVN?

Comment: Hope you are working on windows and using Tortoise svn client. In the commit window there is a check box `show unversioned files`. Have you tried un-checking this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion

Comment: @DipuH - yes, but it hides only unversioned files. The extensions I have mentioned have already been checked in to SVN much before and I am not allowed to delete them. When I take latest, I also get those but I don't have to check in them again.

Comment: This is not a Delphi question. It's a pure SVN question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I just wanted to give examples of extensions which are in Delphi, that's why I added Delphi tag there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You **must** (for new files of these types) define svn:ignore properties
2. For already versioned files, which you don't want commit even if they are changed (BTW, storing vuild-artifacts in repository is bad, ugly and stupid workflow) **if you commit using TortoiseSVN** you have and can add all these files to special local changelist (TortoiseSVN-specific, ignored by other clients) "ignore-on-commit"

But **The Right Way (tm)** is svn:ignore these file-types, remove from repository (create copy files outside WC before, because removing from repo remove file from WC) and have these artifacts as local-only ignored by SVN files in Working Copies