# About eclipse metadata, How can I just upload project metadata without the eclipse ide metadata to svn?

Tags: java, eclipse

I think the Eclipse metadata can divided to class:

1, about the project metadata.

2, about the eclipse IDE itself, such as prerefrences for syntax color, font etc.

I want my team member share the 1) not the 2)

How can I do this?

p.s.

it seems that the 1) is stored in the project folder's .settings folder, and the 2) is stored in the workspace .metadata folder, if this is the true, then It will be easy to achieve my goal, is it the true?

Comment: Presumably you'd identify the files and use [svn ignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion) on them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion

Comment: I don't think color and font shared if you just commit project folder

Comment: Preferences which apply to the whole workspace are saved in the .metadata not the project .settings. Can you be more explicit about what you want to share.

Comment: just share project information, without the team member's prereference settings of the IDE