# How to ignore .dll files from checkin in team explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, team-explorer

I have a project on visualstudio.com and I am connecting to it from VisualStudio 2013, In the team explorer, how to ignore .dll files from checkin?
I was doing the same in svn like this [How do I ignore files in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Team Foundation Version Control, you can create [`.tfignore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore) files in folders in your workspace to ignore any files that VS is not ignoring by default.

If you're using Git version control, you can create a [`.gitignore`](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) file. You can get a .gitignore for your project type [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore), or go into Settings in Visual Studio Team Explorer to add one automatically.

You can check-in/commit tfignore and gitignore files into source control so that the specified files are ignored for everyone. Any files that were already added to the repository will not be affected, however; those have to be removed manually.