# SVN ignoring.txt does not seem to work in Zend Studio

Tags: svn, ignore, svnignore

I added `ignoring.txt` at the root of my project. Inside it I have this:

```
php.tags
.local.vimrc
```

For some reason when I bring back these two files and try to commit I see them in the list of files to commit. I did commit the `ignoring.txt` file. Is there a step that I am missing?

Also, I have never committed the two files. They are both seen as new.

I am using Zend Studio 12.5 on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more research and testing. It turns you are right they are no standard for using ignoring.txt.

But there is a way to more easily manage files that you want SVN to ignore.

Here are two alias's that I created to help me to more quickly manage my ignore files for SVN:

```
alias svnshowignore='svn pg -R svn:ignore .'
alias svnupignore='svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .'
```

The name of the file is now: .svnignore

The only thing you have to do is edit it and inside add the files you want SVN to ignore. After saving the file in the folder of that file you use this command: svnupignore This command will take the list of files inside the .svnignore and add them to the ignore list.

The other command is for listing the ignore files by SVN.

Comment: This doesn't update dynamically.  You have to repeatedly run the svnupignore command.  In addition it has nothing to do with your original question of ignoring.txt which doesn't exist as a feature.

Comment: It has something to do with it. I just changed the name of the file. I use .svnignore so that it stays hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might be a new feature that I do not know about ignoring.txt is nothing that I am familiar with.  To ignore files please follow the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion).

Comment: It seems there is a way to use a file to do this but for some reason it as not work out for me.