# SVN ignore files doesn't work

Tags: svn

I'm fighting with svn at the moment.

My situation is simple :
I have a working copy, let's call this folder `wc`.
In my working copy, I want to put in a lot of folders, but I want some of them, and some of the files inside them not to be added (ignored so).

I tried to use `propset` on `.` to ignore a single file (test.js), but here is the problem :

- When I use `svn add .`, nothing is added.
- When I use `svn add *`, everything is added. It's like using `proset svn:ignore` is useless (even though I got the message saying the prop was set).
- I made a `main` folder, and tried to put all inside, propsetting it, and did the two above commands : same result.
- I also tried to version the folder and propsetting it, then trying to add the subfolders, I get the same problem.

  - Edit : I tried `svn propset svn:ignore "*lolo*" main` and then `svn add --force main`, it works halfway, as `main/lolo` is ignored, `main/totololototo` is ignored, but `main/baba/lolo` is not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

This will open your editor. Write the list of files and directories your want to ignore. Save and close the editor.

Then commit the changes:

```
$ svn ci -m "ignoring some file" .
```

See also:

- [How do I ignore files in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion)
- [How to ignore a directory with SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn)

Comment: I did the exact same thing with propedit instead of propset, didnt change anything