# Should I commit all directory changes after svn:ignore all .iml files?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, command-line, svnignore

On a project I am working on in IntelliJ, the IDE generates a bunch of files of type .iml. When looking at `svn st` in my project directory, all these files are shown. Not wanting to commit all of these IDE related files to my repository, I chose to ignore this file type (as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion)):

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*.iml" .
```

However, now my project is showing all of my sub-directories as modified when I check subversion status (`svn st`). I don't want to look through a massive list of modifications when preparing to commit changes, but I feel hesitant to commit all these modified directories.

First question: Is ignoring the .iml files a good practice when committing IntelliJ projects?

Second question: Is it safe to commit all my project directories that have been modified as a result of ignoring the .iml files?

Update: I decided to roll back the ignore on .iml files, as the list of .iml files is shorter than the list of modified directories I would have to commit. I still don't feel that I have found a clear best practice for this. Anyone who regularly codes with IntelliJ IDE have a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: Are those `.iml` files generated automatically from other items that *are* versioned, or specific to your user/workstation? If so then yes, you should not version those (and ignoring will help you with that).

Question 2: If all you're committing is the property changes for the directories, then yes. If you have changed files that you're *also* committing, will those break the build or otherwise violate any rules your dev process has for what should & shouldn't be committed (and when)?

My rule of thumb is that each commit should be associated with only one change. So in this case, I would commit *just* the `svn:ignore` property changes, and if I had other uncommitted changes I'd commit them separately. Reason being that if I have to roll back a change later, I don't lose change A because change B was in the same commit, even though they're unrelated.