# SVN ignore recursively all .js files in folder

Tags: svn, typescript

I have a typescript application where I'd like to ignore all compiled JavaScript files in the folder with SVN.  Is there any command or shortcut to do this for all files under a folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86052/121694).

If you'd like to ignore files/file patterns recursively for all directories under a parent, in Subversion 1.8 and later you can use [svn:global-ignores](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) property. Equivalent functionality is available prior to Subversion 1.8, but it requires each client to configure their [runtime configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html) (`[global-ignores]` section of config file).