# Subversion: how to ignore *.log files

Tags: svn, svnignore

I know the subject [was treated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion), but I'm trying to ignore *.log files under linux and it doesn't work. I issued the command

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*.log" .
```

but when I do `svn st` .log files are still shown, like:

```
$ svn st
M       myfile.log
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Commit this change first. BTW, ignores affect **unversioned** files only. This one is versioned.

Comment: thank you!! Is this the correct way to unversion a file? svn rm --keep-local my_file?

Comment: yep, it should work. Don't forget to run `svn commit`