# Cannot ignore files in Subversion with an external `.svnignore` file

Tags: windows, svn, ignore, svnignore

I need to exclude some files from Subversion, using a `.svnignore` file:

```
> more .svnignore

*.obj
*.abc
*.aaa

> touch f1.cpp
> touch f2.abc
> svn add --force ./
A    f1.cpp
A    f2.abc
```

Why is `f2.abc` added to the repository, even if its extension should not allow that?

Answer (score 4):

After modifying `.svnignore`, I had to re-run:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove possible misinterpretations of Pietro's self-answer

It's obvious, that in SVN it's not enough to put file .svnignore or something like this in the root of you repository folder, unlike Hg or Git, because **only relevant properties** of files or dirs have effect.

But, because command `svn propset` have option `-F` for reading patterns from external file (and setting new properties remove all old), you *can* use  (any text) file for updating ignore-patterns in the whole repository in one action

In order to mimics Git|Hg style of ignoring more deeply, everybody (with Python) can install and use [SVN-Ignore](https://pypi.org/project/SVN-Ignore/) from Pypi, which add

- A .svnignore file that lets you specify which files should be ignored
- The possibility to add exceptions(Lines starting with !) to the SVN Ignore file
- Updating the svn:ignore property every time you add new files