# How to pass a literal asterisk to svn propset on Windows command line and bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, svn, command-line

The goal is to set the following svn property in a `.bat` file:

```
Properties on 'logs':
  svn:ignore
    *
```

The command should be `svn propset svn:ignore * logs` but the asterisk needs to be escaped somehow.
I don't want to add the current list of files I really want to ignore all files in the logs directory without ignoring the logs directory itself.

However I can't figure out how to properly escape the asterisk to get a literal asterisk in the svn property.

- `'*'` results in the string `'*'` (with the quotes) to be set as the value which does not ignore any files at all
- `"*"` or `^*` still expands the asterisk causing svn to set a property (with the name of a file in the current directory) on all directories.
- `\*` or `"\*"` causes SVN to look for a (or all?) files in the root of the `C:` drive for some reason
- `%*` results in a value of `%*`

I can't think of any other way to escape a character in a bat file.

Comment: Don't know for the specific mix of windows and svn, sorry. more things to try \052 - the octal for *. Some use of -- to ensure the argument is not treated as a filename - like filenames and branches are distinguished.

Comment: Maybe [How do I ignore files in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/)

Comment: @JosefZ Doubtful, as that is more to do with auto-commit. But worth mentioning :-)

Comment: @JosefZ: that is what I am trying to do here but I need to pass a literal asterisk instead of a filename. Note that e.g. `"*.txt"` has the desired effect but not `"*"`

Comment: Sorry I can't comprehend  meaning of *literal asterisk* in `svn` context. If  `"*.txt"`  works then try `"*.*"`…

Comment: @JosefZ: `svn propset svn:ignore "*.*" logs` also adds the name of file(s) from the current directory to the svn:ignore proerties of all directories. I must have missed something earlier because I cannot reproduce getting "*.txt"to work. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same problem you described.
I am on Windows (using TortoiseSVN) and I needed to set a rule in `svn:ignore` so that all files belonging to certain directories would be ignored.
I used the following command:

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*' dirname
```

And then In File Explorer, went to dirname and then: `Right Click>Properties>Subversion>Properties..`.
I saw that the value set for property `svn:ignore` was `'*'` which didn't worked at all.
I also tried different combinations of asterisks (as you said) but without success.
Then, I tried to use a file-based approach: I created a simple `svn.txt` file with just one line:

```
*
```

Then, after execution of the command:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F svn.text dirname
```

I went to the same menu described before, and now the `svn:ignore` property for the folder correctly shows the value: `*`.
Of course, after committing the `svn:ignore` property modification, every file which is put under `dirname` is correctly ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two other ways to try but sadly I cannot verify them myself without further ado...

1. Maybe it is a double caret ^^*
2. You can try to fix it by passing the asterisk as variable inside of your batch file. Example:

```
@echo off
[...]
set asterisk=*
call svn propset svn:ignore %asterisk% logs
[...]
```

This should prevent the expansion of the asterisk since the variable %asterisk% must already be expanded and there is no second expansion pass unless you activated  `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` somewhere in your command session (with `cmd.exe /V:ON` or `SETLOCAL`).

Remark to your attempt with `\*`: 
This behavior seems totally legit to me, since `\` stands for the root directory of the current drive in UNIX/LINUX. And svn interprets wildcards as implemented in `fnmatch` on such systems [see redbook on svn:ignore]. This essentially works in Windows also this way. `cd \` will bring you to the first level of the drive and a `dir \*.*` will list the files on the first level no matter where you are in the sub directories.

Hope this helps. Good luck with your project :)