# How to ADD a file to svn:global-ignores?

Tags: svn

According to answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86049/607407) you can ignore a file in the whole project tree like this:

```
svn propset svn:global-ignores "ignoreThis.txt" .
```

The problem is, I already have files in `svn:global-ignores` and if I run the above command, they all get replaced by `ignoreThis.txt`.

So how can I add a value to the global ignores property rather than replacing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property value is a just a newline terminated list of the paths you want to ignore. If the property already exists the best option, assuming you have a working copy already available, is to use `svn propedit svn:global-ignores .` This will open the existing property value in your `EDITOR`. You can then edit the list and save to set the new value. Then just commit the property change.