# Create Project from Cloned git Repository in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, tfs, repository

I have a Project, let's call it "WebFormsProject". I work and work and work, then I add source control and commit to my local repository.

I then connect to a remote repository and push my files to Visual Studio Online.

Now I have an upstream Master Branch that I can sync my local repository up with. Now I wan to bring another developer in on the project, I add them to the project in Visual Studio online.We go to his machine and we clone the repository.

Now, when I click on Solutions Tab, Solutions is empty.....

How do I create a Solution for this cloned repository. Just like I have on my machine?

Lets Recap, I have a  Solution on my machine as well as a local repo I commit to, I have a remote repository I can sync up with. My partner has cloned my repo and now has only a local repository. How does he get a solution to start working with?

Comment: Is the sln file under source control or just the project directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you have versioned the .sln file, your partner should only have to double-click on it to open his Visual Studio and start working on the same project.

But make sure to modify that .sln as described in "[Visual Studio keeps changing project.sln file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9694050/6309)" in order to avoid modification to the `ProjectGuid` element each time someone is opening said solution.