# Visual studio ipch folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution

I need to send the solution which consists of 2 projects by email.
Can I delete ipch folder?

Comment: Should be safe, so yes! The folder and the files in there will be regenerated when building the solution. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/1ef46540-e4b8-4779-8403-49239bc3f7ee

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's the folder used by the IntelliSense parser to store precompiled header files.  It will be rebuilt on the receiver's machine.  More in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922660/which-visual-c-file-types-should-be-committed-to-version-control/3923352#3923352).  Use Build + Clean to avoid having to look at too many of them.

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer in the MSDN support forums:

> I'm not only a C# moderator but also a C++ user :}  The ipch directory
>   and the many, many new files generated by the compiler can be safely
>   deleted.  In fact they should be deleted (and probably are) for clean
>   builds.  I teach a C++ college class myself and here is what I require
>   my students to do. In the solution folder delete all bin, obj, ipch,
>   debug and release directories.
>
> 1. Delete any .suo files
> 2. Delete any .user files
> 3. Delete any .ncb files
> 4. Delete any .sbr files
> 5. Delete any .*log files (for VS 2010)
>
> Zip up the entire solution directory for submission.  This ensures
>   that the solution and project structure remain intact.

The answer link:
[Is it safe to delete "ipch" folder - Pre-compiled headers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ef46540-e4b8-4779-8403-49239bc3f7ee/is-it-safe-to-delete-ipch-folder-precompiled-headers)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here: [How to change ipch path in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980701/how-to-change-ipch-path-in-visual-studio-2012)
Change to "always use fallback location" in this way this directory does not get created inside your solution but the system temp directory is used. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete these files with this simple windows command:

```
    project_folder> del *.log *.ipch *.suo *.user *.ncb *.sbr *.vc.db *.obj /s /q
```