# How to change ipch path in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I saw that VS2012 creates some files in the solution folder(.sdf, .suo, .ipch, etc). Is it possible to change the folder where these files are created?

The methods for VS2010 don't work in VS2012, see screenshot:
[image]

Comment: FYI according to the comment in your screenshot, you can get to the property sheets from `VIEW > Other Windows > Property Manager`. Property sheets are used so that you can better control how you reuse these properties across solutions. However, this doesn't solve your problem as I don't see a way to set ipch path via `VC++ Directories`.

Comment: You can set a Fallback location for the IntelliSense database in Text Editor, C/C++, Advanced.  Never tried this myself.  You can't move the .suo.  The .ipch is already in a separate directory.  There's little point in tinkering with this.

Comment: Well why I ask it is because I run a command to pack my project files into a .zip after a succesful build, and I don't really like those files residing there and taking up 50 times more space than the project itself.

Comment: In that case, you should either change your command to ignore VS files, or isolate your solution file from your projects, copy the projects/source and then include the solution file separately.

Answer (score 8):

Go to **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Text Editor** -> **C/C++** -> **Advanced**

In the "**Fallback Location**", set "**Always Use Fallback Location**" to `True` and "**Do Not Warn If Fallback Location Used**" to `True`. In "**Fallback Location**" you can either leave it blank and VS will use your `%TEMP%` folder, or specify a different location of your choice.

(Note the .suo files will still sit next to your solutions)