# Should I add other files to git except .cpp?

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, gitignore

When I created a C++ console project in Visual Studio, I found that besides `.cpp` files, I had other files like `.sln`, `.vcxproj`, `.filters`, `.user`.

Should I add them to Git repo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Visual C++ file types should be committed to version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922660/which-visual-c-file-types-should-be-committed-to-version-control)

Comment: With `CMake` and out of source building I put all generated files (including the Visual Studio project files) in a separate folder tree so they don't end up in my repositories. I do have the `CMakeLists.txt` in the repository so the visual studio (or other IDE's) project files can be generated on a different system.

Answer (score 3):

You can download a `.gitignore` for Visual Studio. It will make sure only what's necessary to open and work on the project would be tracked, the rest would be ignored.

You can download one from here:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore